# Consultar monto total de compras, cantidad de compras realizadas y fecha mas reciente de la ultima compra

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo la tabla

| id_cliente | cantidad_trans | monto | fecha |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 100 | 13/8/20222 |
| 1 | 2 | 100 | 12/8/2022 |
| 1 | 2 | 50 | 5/7/2022 |
| 1 | 3 | 50 | 25/7/2022 |

el resultao que quiero es

| Una cabecera | Otra cabecera | monto | fecha_ultima_trans |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 200 | 13/8/2022 |
| 1 | 5 | 100 | 25/7/2022 |

estoy utilizando sql server

Comment: está agrupado por mes?

Comment: @Lamak si es por mes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Este es el código que da el resultado de más arriba

Select id_cliente,
Sum(cantidad)as cantidad,
Sum (monto) as monto,
Max(fecha)from hist_trans
group by max(month (fecha)),id_cliente
Order by max(month (fecha)) desc

Comment: Mediante la edición de tu pregunta agrega los detalles que falten pues este espacio es solo para respuesta, posterior eliminar esta *no respuesta*

Comment: Este resultado no es correcto, sólo va a funcionar cuando tengas fechas del mismo año. Lo otro es que finalmente sí usaste la misma lógica que puse en mi query y la que dijiste que no funcionaría

Answer (score 2):

Esto debería ser relativamente simple:

```
SELECT
    id_cliente,
    SUM(cantidad_trans) cantidad_trans,
    SUM(monto) monto,
    MAX(fecha) fecha_ultima_trans
FROM dbo.Tabla t
GROUP BY
    id_cliente,
    CONVERT(varchar(6),fecha,112)
;
```

Comment: Ese query no me funciona, ese solo trae un registro con la suma total pero lo que necesito es la suma total de cada mes y la fecha del último consumo de cada mes ejemplo I'd 1 hizo en mayo total de 13 trans por un total 1000 su fecha de último consumo en mayo fue 30/5

Comment: Lo mismo para el mes de abril y el resto de meses

Comment: Si pones corres ese query el resultado que te dará según las tablas de arriba será I'd 1 cantidad 9 monto 300 fecha 13/8/2022

Comment: pues no, probaste la query?. Si ves, estoy agrupando por el mes, así que lo que comentas no va a pasar

Comment: Te recomiendo que primeros pruebes la consulta que puse y luego revises los resultados

Answer (score 0):

Hola creo que tu consulta puede parecer a lo siguiente:

```
Select TOP SUM(cantidad_trans) AS transacciones, SUM(monto) AS monto, fecha
WHERE id_cliente = @id
ORDER BY fecha ASC
```

Espero te ayude o te de una idea.

Saludos

Comment: No ese query no funcionaría ya lo había probado